# Select in MaterializeCSS is not populated with data from VUE

Tags: css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, materialize

Goodnight.

I am working with VUE and MaterializeCSS. Trying to fill in a selection of but I have not succeeded.

I receive the data from the database correctly but when highlighting a V-FOR on the options of the select these are kept blank.

Does anyone know the reason? Thank you.

Code:

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                                    <select name="categoría" v-model="category_id">
                                        <option v-for="category in arrayCategories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <label>Materialize Select</label>
                                </div>         
                            </div>
```

If I make an HTML PRE the data is correct:

```
<pre>{{arrayCategories}}</pre>
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Category 1"
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
         <select v-for="category in arrayCategories" :key="category.id" name="categoría" model="category_id">
    <option  :value="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
         </select>
         <label>Materialize Select</label>
       </div>         
     </div>
```